# Wireshark Display Filters

Tags: networking, wireshark

I'm a beginner in wireshark and i have an a task for the following wireshark display filters:

a- only packets from a specific network interface car ex: Intel
b- only unicast traffic
c- any traffic except from/to www.vgtu.lt

Answer (score 0):

a) In wireshark in the menu bar capture->interfaces you can specify the interface to capture

b) (eth.dst[0] & 1) will display the multicast and broadcast packets . you can use the not expression of this to display only unicast messages .

!(eth.dst[0] & 1)

c) !(http.host eq "www.vgtu.lt") but this will not show only http packets .

you can use nslookup tool to get the ip address of the domain name  www.vgtu.lt

C:\Users\praveen>nslookup www.vgtu.lt
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.169.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    web.vgtu.lt
Address:  158.129.192.20
Aliases:  www.vgtu.lt

now you can use the filter !(ip.addr == 158.129.192.20)